# How to add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know how to add or create a custom HTTP header using JavaScript or jQuery?

i am using below code but it is giving me **405 Method not Allowed**. 
i am using **POST** Method but in Request Method but its showing me **OPTION** in Request Method.
Status Code:405 Method not Allowed, when i am using postman it is working and showing me 200 ok status code. does anyone help me what is the issue is going on. 
i am using below code in HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'http://api.XXXXXXXXXX.com/SharedServices/SharedData.svc/rest/Authenticate',
        data: {
            "ClientId": "ApiIntegration",
            "UserName": "XXXXX",
            "Password": "XXXXX@123",
            "EndUserIp": "192.168.1.10"
        },
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"},

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
})
```

what will be correct jQuery code, if there is an issue in my code.
here is the screenshot of postman witch i am using.

[image]

Comment: probably a CORS issue in that case

Comment: This has nothing to do with headers. The OPTION request is a pre-flight to ensure that CORS is supported on the receiving domain. From the 405 response it would appear that it is not, so what you are trying would not work in JS due to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: `"cache-control": "no-cache"` — Why are you trying to set that on a **request** header?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no issue in jQuery code this is because you made a cross origin request. try to use in this way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPSjxg4Rzs8

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 2):

When you make a cross origin request, the server must provide [access control headers (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to give your JavaScript permission to read the response.

A typical request is considered *simple*, but if you add certain characteristics to it then it stops being simple and becomes a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

One of those characteristics is "It sets custom headers in the request", so by adding custom headers, you have made it complex.

Before the browser makes the POST request, it will send the preflight request which is an OPTIONS request.

It must receive a response from the server giving it permission to make the POST request before it will make that POST request.

When the browser makes the OPTIONS request to the server, it is currently returning an error saying "You aren't allowed to make OPTIONS requests to this URL!".

You need to change the server so it:

- accepts the OPTIONS request
- responds with the headers that grant permission to make the POST request

Comment: @AjayKumar — The reason that my answer says nothing about changing the jQuery code is because changing the jQuery code is not the solution. The solution is described at the end of the answer, in the section starting: **You need to change the server**.